# SSH port forwarding configuration for accessing a TCP port on a virtual machine from another virtual machine running the on same host hardware

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

### Scenario

I have the an Industrial PC that has two Operating Systems (virtual machines):

1. Real-Time Operating System that can talk to PLC controllers
2. Generic Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) Distribution

The only connection available between these two Operating Systems is through a virtual network.

#### Virtual Network

- Linux Host has `192.168.3.1` set as IP address
- RTOS Host has `192.168.3.2` set as IP Address

#### Data

Data generated by the PLC controller is controlled and configured by a port `8580` which is accessible to the Linux Host i.e., `192.168.3.2:8580` (There is a OPC-UA Server running on the RTOS which is available on port `8580`)

[image: Scenario Description Diagram]

### Requirements

I wish to create an SSH Tunnel on the Linux Machine so that I can access the port `8580` from the the RTOS for an end-user to read data from the OPC UA server via the IP address of the Linux Machine provided via DHCP.

End-user can read data from `<IP-address-PC>:8580` (Here `IP-address-PC` is not the same as that of Virtual Network but obtained from DHCP Server)

However, I wish to create a *Secure, Timed Session* on this tunnel.

#### *Secure, Timed Session*

- The tunnel should be created for a limited amount of time
- The tunnel once created, should only allow **one and only one Session**
- Once the session closes, the tunnel closes

### Initial Investigations

I went through the [`wikibooks for OpenSSH Tunneling Chapter`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Tunnels#Tunneling%20Via%20A%20Single%20Intermediate%20Host) and it mentions the use of **Tunneling via Single Intermediate Host** which might seem to serve the purpose

#### Breaking it down

```bash
ssh -f -g -L 8580:192.168.3.2:8580 admin@localhost sleep 60
```

`-f`: run the process in background

`-g`: allow remote users to access the local port (8580 on linux)

`-L`: local port forwarding on whatever happens on RTOS `192.168.3.2:8580` forward it here

`admin@localhost`: It turns out the RTOS has no SSH on it so the only way to maintain this tunnel is to maintain the connection to `localhost`. I still need to give a password at the execution of the command initially

`sleep 60`: wait till the user tries to connect to the server for 60 seconds, if cannot connect close the tunnel

I think I have solved the timed tunnel issue with the `sleep 60`.

### `sshd_config` and Session

I wish to setup the tunnel so that only one session is available. Is this possible to control?

How would I be able to codify the steps above into a configuration for `sshd_config` and perhaps with a *one-time* user who is not `admin`?

### Edit

Based on some specific requirements, the user actually triggers the `ssh` command above manually upon wishing to obtain the data from the RTOS. I am on the lookout for mechanism which may close the SSH tunnel upon some *inactivity* after a certain amount of time.

In a lot of cases, user might just want to *peek* into the data from the OPC-UA server and upon satisfaction would like to close the tunnel for security reasons.

Comment: Can you explain the term "session" or provide a reference to an explanation? This term appears on a web site about OPC UA, but I didn't find enough details. What defines the start and end of a session? How could the tunneling software detect the end of the session?

Comment: @Bodo good catch! I am still trying to find some relevant documentation on the "session". What about at the moment, some time based mechanism? Close tunnel after x Seconds.

Comment: I don't know if this requirement "Close tunnel after x Seconds" is useful. To me it is not clear *why* you want the tunnel to close after a session or after some time. How is the tunnel established when it is needed (again)? By a manual `ssh` command? What would be the risk if the tunnel was permanent? Please [edit] your question to provide this background information.

Comment: @Bodo added the description additionally. As mentioned, the trigger happens manually of the `ssh` command (depending on wish of the user). Security implications remain a bit high since the OPC Server may be connected directly to Operational Technology and upon exposing the port long time could be a vulnerability for attackers to take control